in JS what is more efficient for determining if a string is one of many options: compare with multiple ORs or switch?
Example: I want to see if a key press is one of 4 different keys.
Option 1:
if(e.key === "ArrowUp"   ||
   e.key === "ArrowDown" ||
   e.key === "Control"   ||
   e.key === "Escape"    || ){
   // do stuff
}

vs

 switch(e.key){
        case "ArrowUp":
        case "ArrowDown":
        case "Control":
        case "Escape":
            // do stuff
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


There are many resources out there showing that a switch statement is more performant than multiple ifs. But what about a single if with multiple ORs vs a switch statement?

What did your testing reveal? And which browsers did you test with? And does it really matter for your program compared to other timings? How often are the key state updates available?

added some tests

I would also try if ([ "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", ...].includes(e.key), just for curiosity's sake. I expect the difference to be negligible in any case, see @AndrewMorton 's comment, but in some cases this might be a more compact representation.

Don't measure just one run, execute it 1000, 1000000 or more times so that the time spent on the test run is significant.

I have significantly expanded the tests, interesting results!

You may want to post your benchmark results as an answer, instead of editing the question

@Bergi good point, added!

It was suggested to run some benchmarks and also include includes so here they are:

function testOr(k){
if(k === "ArrowUp"   ||
   k === "ArrowDown" ||
   k === "Control"   ||
   k === "Escape"    ){
   return true
 }
}

function testSwitch(k){
 switch(k){
        case "ArrowUp":
        case "ArrowDown":
        case "Control":
        case "Escape":
            return true
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

function testIncludes(k){
  if([ "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "Control", "Escape"].includes(k)){return true}
}


function test(x, fn, k){
    const start = Date.now();
    for (let i=0; i<k; i++){
    fn(x)
  }
  console.log(`total time spent: ${Date.now()-start}`)
}


const iterations = [ 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000 ]

// testing begins
iterations.forEach(t=>test("ArrowUp", testOr, t)) // finding first element
iterations.forEach(t=>test("Escape", testOr, t)) // finding last element
iterations.forEach(t=>test("asdf", testOr, t)) // finding nothing
// repeated for testSwitch and testIncludes

Results (in ms):



switch
or
includes
input type
iterations




0
0
0
first element
1000


2
2
4
first element
10000


20
17
40
first element
100000


206
195
378
first element
1000000


1
1
1
last element
1000


2
3
3
last element
10000


22
24
43
last element
100000


236
256
381
last element
1000000


1
0
1
not included
1000


2
2
3
not included
10000


28
27
36
not included
100000


273
270
392
not included
1000000



Plotted (lower = better):



It seems like the answer is:

includes is less performant with scale
when it comes to finding the first element, or performs the best (wins by 11ms)
but when it comes to finding the last element, switch performs the best (wins by 20ms)
when it comes to finding no elements at all, or is juuust better than switch by 3ms

Moral of the story: don't use includes, switch is the way to go for the worst case scenario, or is the way to go for best case scenario.

hum, could you add const testRegex = s => /ArrowUp|ArrowDown|Control|Escape/.test(s); ?

You should add an observable side effect, e.g. matches += fn() ? 1 :0; - otherwise a good compiler might just inline fn and prune the side effect free parts (= the whole function). Also I disagree to your conclusion, your benchmark shows no measurable difference (it is not statistically significant)

I did some tests myself and I managed to get the best results by using bitwise OR instead of only OR in the if-statement. But since my result times are way different than yours, I can't say its generally better

C# builds a hash table for switch statements with more than about 8 cases to make it faster. It could be that the JS JIT compiler will use the same technique, so make sure you don't dismiss switch in favour of if+or in general.

@JonasWilms good point I agree they may not be significantly different, I re-ran some of these and the times are slightly different but not by a large margin, I assume likely due to the laptop being plugged in vs not, how many programs are running in the bg, etc. I'm new to this kind of performance testing so advice is appreciated. I will try with the side effect approach soon

@TiKay can you show your approach using bitwise OR?

@NullSalad I just took your code and replaced || with |

@Null Salad, as you mentioned, the switch-case statement is generally more performant than an if-else statement, especially when dealing with large if-else ladders compared to their equivalent switch representation. You can find more details here
In this particular case, if you have a small number of conditions, the performance difference between if-else and switch-case is negligible. The only factor that matters is readability, and personally, I find if-else to be the better option.

I would not cite a book from 2010 on performance - that was pre JIT compilers - most of the advice is terribly outdated (e.g. manually building a duffs device does not make much sense as JIT compilers can unroll loops much more efficiently)
